# Offset guides label in case of text overlapping in amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I would like to include guides into my amcharts graphs and I found very descriptive examples. However I'm struggling with positioning of label text, especially in case when guides are so close that labels overlap.

Here is example code https://jsfiddle.net/Tripy/1wwygcy7/2/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var chartData = weekendGuides = [];
generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate( firstDate.getDate() - 200 );
    firstDate.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
        newDate.setDate( newDate.getDate() + i );
        var a1 = Math.round( Math.random() * ( 40 + i ) ) + 100 + i;
        var b1 = Math.round( Math.random() * ( 1000 + i ) ) + 500 + i * 2;
        chartData.push( {
            "date": newDate,
            "value": a1,
            "volume": b1
        } );

        // add weekend guide
        if ( 6 == newDate.getDay() ) {
            var toDate = new Date( newDate );
            toDate.setDate( newDate.getDate() + 2 );
            weekendGuides.push( {
                "date": newDate,
                "toDate": toDate,
                "lineAlpha": 0,
                "fillAlpha": 0.05,
                "fillColor": "#000",
                "expand": true
            } );
        }
    }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "stock",
    "dataSets": [ {
        "title": "first data set",
        "fieldMappings": [ {
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
        }, {
            "fromField": "volume",
            "toField": "volume"
        } ],
        "dataProvider": chartData,
        "categoryField": "date"
    } ],
    "panels": [ {
        "showCategoryAxis": false,
        "title": "Value",
        "percentHeight": 70,
        "stockGraphs": [ {
            "id": "g1",
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
            "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
        } ],
        "stockLegend": {
            "periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%",
            "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
        },
        "categoryAxis": {
            "guides": weekendGuides
        },
        "valueAxes": [ {
            "guides": [ {
                "value": 325,
                "lineAlpha": 0.8,
                "lineColor": "#0c0",
                "label": "Guide #1",
                "position": "right"
            }, {
                "value": 322,
                "lineAlpha": 0.8,
                "lineColor": "#0c0",
                "label": "Guide #2",
                "position": "right"
            }]
        } ]
    } ],
    "chartScrollbarSettings": {
        "graph": "g1"
    },
    "chartCursorSettings": {
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        "fullWidth": true,
        "cursorAlpha": 0.1
    },
    "periodSelector": {
        "position": "bottom",
        "periods": [ {
            "period": "MM",
            "selected": true,
            "count": 1,
            "label": "1 month"
        }, {
            "period": "YYYY",
            "count": 1,
            "label": "1 year"
        }, {
            "period": "YTD",
            "label": "YTD"
        }, {
            "period": "MAX",
            "label": "MAX"
        } ]
    }
} );
```

Any idea how to push label text below the guide for guides in case that labels are overlapping. Perhaps with CSS code for class name amcharts-guide-[id]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this through the guide properties properties, but you have the right hunch with the css class name. Set [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#addClassNames) to `true`, give your guides IDs and then add a [`drawn`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#drawn) event listener in your stock panel that adjusts the desired guide(s) directly by calling `querySelector` on the `.amcharts-guide-[id] tspan` selector and adjusting the y attribute:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "addClassNames": true,
  // ...
  "stockPanels": [{
    "valueAxes": [{
      "guides": [{
        "id": "guide-1",
        // ..
      }, {
        "id": "guide-2",
        // ..
      }]
    }],
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "drawn",
      "method": function() {
        var guide2Text = document.querySelector('.amcharts-guide-guide-2 tspan');
        if (guide2Text) {
          guide2Text.setAttribute('y', 20);
        }
      }
    }]    
  }],
  // ..
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wwygcy7/3/)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I have just changed guide2Text.setAttribute('y', 20); to guide2Text.setAttribute('x', 20); as I have vertical guides. What happens in case I have multiple guides overlapping. I just double the listeners and adapt querySelector to 2nd .amcharts-guide-[id] span or there is another way?

Comment: You don't need to add additional listeners. Just add the additional querySelector calls for each guide that overlaps in the same listener. If every guide overlaps, you may want to consider looping through the guides and staggering the x value so that they're each adjusted differently or adjust every other label.